# Failed to install laser printer samsung ML-1676 on Fedora 17

Tags: linux, installation, drivers, fedora

I downloaded installation packet from official site, but it is not compatible with latest Fedora releases(too many things changed in services,settings,device names et.)

Anyway - when i connect the printer via usb, device appears /dev/usb/lp0
Can anyone tell me how to install drivers correctly, and what else should i do to use the printer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any drivers to install, since this seems to be a fairly standard printer.

Just open

```
    http://localhost:631/admin
```

Login with username root and your root password

Check if your printer is auto-detected with "find new printers", this will probably not be the case.

Else add a new printer, you will have to select your specific model in a list.

To sum up, the printers are already installed, you just need to configure CUPS .

Good luck !